# Find and replace names in name manager

Tags: excel, vba

In the `name manager` I have the following list:

```
Product_A_Brand_A
Product_A_Brand_B
Product_A_Brand_C
Product_A_Brand_D
Product_C_Brand_A
Product_C_Brand_B
```

Now, I want to replace `Product_A` by `Product_B`. 
I could do this manually by going through each `name` in the `name manager`.

However, I am wondering if there is a solution in `VBA` that goes through all the names and replaces them with the new input. 
The same it is done with the `find-and-replace` function in an Excel file:

```
Sub Find_Replace_Values()
Sheet1.Range("A1:A10").Replace What:="Product_A", Replacement:="Product_B"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a routine like below to do this.

```
Sub Find_Replace_Names()
    Dim nm As Name
    For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
        If InStr(1, nm.Name, "Product_A", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            nm.Name = Replace(nm.Name, "Product_A", "Product_B", , , vbTextCompare)
        End If
    Next nm
End Sub
```